# uib-tabset directive load conditionally

Tags: angularjs

I have a uib-tabset as below.

```
<uib-tabset active="activeJustified" justified="true">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Address" >
        <by-adr></by-adr>

    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="1" heading="country" >
       <by-country></by-country>
    </uib-tab>
```

When the page loads my Database call inside the controller of both the directives are called instead I want to call the controller inside directive to be called only when the tab is selected.can Some body help me in this.when country tab is selected then I should call Database call in by-country directive.Instead of loading all at one time.I am using angularJS 1.x

I am trying to Load the directive only when the tab is selected.Example when I click country tab then I want my  by-country directive to load.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your full code but you can do following:

#### $broadcast

once you loaded data from database, you can fire event to your directives (suppose they are loaded already)

In root controller:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('onDBLoaded', {});
```

and in directive controller:

```
$scope.$on("onDBLoaded", function() {
   run();  // run your main logic
});
```

Comment: Thx.I am trying to Load the directive only when the tab is selected.Example when I click country tab then I want my  by-country directive to load.